# ¿Cuál es la palabra correcta en español para "scan"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Estaba escribiendo un correo electrónico sobre scans de un escáner de documentos y me preguntaba cuál es la palabra correcta en español que la sustituye o si se usa scan. Revisé el Diccionario de la Lengua Española en línea de la RAE y no se encuentra ni la palabra scan ni escán.

Gracias de antemano por su atención.

Answer (score 6):

Aunque en el Diccionario de la lengua no aparecen específicamente las formas "escán", o "scan", si aparecen [escáner](https://dle.rae.es/esc%C3%A1ner):

> Del ingl. *scanner*; propiamente 'el que explora o registra'.
>
> 1. m. *Electr*. Dispositivo que explora un espacio o imagen y los traduce en señales eléctricas para su procesamiento. *He comprado un escáner para mi computadora.*

[escanear](https://dle.rae.es/escanear):

> 1. tr. Pasar por el escáner.

[escaneo](https://dle.rae.es/escaneo):

> 1. m. Acción de escanear.

[escaneado](https://dle.rae.es/escaneado):

> 1. m. escaneo.

por lo que debe ser válida la forma análoga **escán** (no "scan", ya que se ha adaptado a la forma con "e" inicial).

Además, una búsqueda en internet del término "escán" arroja numerosos resultados en español, e igualmente aparece en [The Free Dictionary](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/escan).

Comment: Si fuese válida, ¿no debería estar en el diccionario? Nunca he visto la palabra "escán", y si la veo fuera de contexto ni se me ocurriría pensar que se refiera a un escáner. Además, la acepción en The Free Dictionary no tiene nada que ver con escáneres, sino con un procedimiento médico

Comment: @AJPerez El diccionario intenta reflejar la existencia de palabras de acuerdo a cierto parámetros, no es en sí el origen de las palabras.

Answer (score 4):

Si "scan" se refiere a la acción de escanear un documento en un escáner, el término correcto sería "escaneado" o "escaneo", como bien indica la otra respuesta. Por ejemplo:

> No abra la tapa del escáner durante el escaneo.
>
> *Don't open the scanner cover during the scan process.*

Si "scan" se refiere al resultado de escanear algo, lo habitual es llamarlo "documento escaneado", "fotografía escaneada", etc. O simplemente abreviarlo como "el escaneo" <sup>(1)</sup>:

> Te envío el documento escaneado de mi partida de nacimiento.
>
> Te envío el escaneo de mi partida de nacimiento. <sup>(1)</sup>
>
> *I'm sending you the scan of my birth certificate.*

La otra respuesta hace referencia a "escán", pero esta palabra no es de uso común (al menos en España), ni está recogida en el diccionario de la RAE. Sí aparece en [The Free Dictionary](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/escan), pero con una acepción distinta, que no está relacionada con los escáneres de documentos, sino con una técnica de medicina. Aunque es cierto que la traducción al Inglés es la misma, "scan", y si una castellanización es válida, también debería serlo la otra.

---

(1) Aunque sí es de uso común, probablemente no sea correcto abreviar "el documento escaneado" como "el escaneo", si atendemos a la definición de la RAE.

Comment: Es otra alternativa, efectivamente

Comment: Pero documento escaneado es el documento al que se le saca copia, no al resultado.

Answer (score 3):

Empecé en el tratamiento de imágenes antes de que existieran *escáneres* en las oficinas y, quizá por eso, nunca he usado *escanear*, sino algo más general que es *digitalizar*.

Hoy en día pides a alguien una imagen de un documento, y ya no utiliza un *escáner*, aunque lo tenga a mano, sino que usa su teléfono, aprovechando estupendas *apps* que corrigen deformaciones e iluminación heterogénea. La gente ya no *escanea*, sino que "hace una foto".

En cualquier caso, *digitalizar* sigue siendo un término válido, se use el dispositivo que se use.